# Ext2 or Ext4 for bootable USB Flash-drive with Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb

I want to install Ubuntu to a USB Flash drive (so I have my Desktop everywhere and can customize it as I want).

I'm still choosing what's the best filesystem for the USB; Ext2 with no journaling or Ext4 with journaling but performance increase? I know that journaling will probably reduce the life of the USB flash drive dramatically, so is Ext2 the obvious choice?

Or is it a bad idea to install Linux (Ubuntu probably) on a USB Flash drive? I tried running a live CD from the USB drive, but it wasn't very customizable - which is the point of carrying my OS with me.